# Wrong label positioning when updating chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am updating my chartjs element with this code:

```
 updateDeumdata: function (obj) {
            deumChart.data.labels.push(obj.x);
            deumChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(obj.y)
            deumChart.update();
        }
```

The issue is that this code adds a new label as first element, and a data (y) as last element without a label. What's wrong? AFAIK `.push` should add at the end of the array.

Comment: Cant reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/zps816o9/

Comment: yes, my fault. Thank you for assising.